# scala mockito, verify args - Wanted but not invoked MockitoSugar

Tags: scala, unit-testing, mockito

```
 class MockitoTest extends MockitoSugar {

  val serviceMock = mock[Service]

  @Test
  def test(): Unit = {

    import org.mockito.Matchers.{eq => eqTo, _} 

    val serviceMock = mock[Service]

    when( serviceMock.call("one") ).
              thenReturn("123")

    verify( serviceMock, times(1) ).call( eqTo("one") )

    val result1 = serviceMock.call("one")
    ...
```

I end up having:

> Wanted but not invoked: service.call("one");
>   -> at mockito.MockitoTest.test(MockitoTest.scala:34) Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

Do I miss something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your test should be structured into three parts:

1. Create mocks for your collaborators, and use `when` to describe their intended behavior
2. Invoke your *system under test* that interacts with those collaborators
3. If necessary, `verify` that some interactions happened.

In your test, you have 2 and 3 reversed, and step 2 invokes the method directly rather than letting your system-under-test invoke it. Your call to `verify` fails because your call to `serviceMock.call("one")` hasn't happened yet.

Instead of this:

```
when( serviceMock.call("one") ).
          thenReturn("123")

verify( serviceMock, times(1) ).call( eqTo("one") )

val result1 = serviceMock.call("one")
```

You want something like this:

```
when( serviceMock.call("one") ).
          thenReturn("123")

/** Instead of val result1 = serviceMock.call("one") directly: */
val systemUnderTest = SystemUnderTest(serviceMock)
systemUnderTest.someMethodThatInvokesServiceCall()

verify( serviceMock, times(1) ).call( eqTo("one") )
```

Comment: how did you import `verify`

Comment: import org.mockito.Mockito.{verify, when, times}

Answer (score 0):

Jeff was right about the sequence of the calls. Just simplified:

Basically "verify" should be after call:

```
  @Test
  def test(): Unit = {

    // GIVEN 
    when( serviceMock. call("one") ).
      thenReturn("123")

    // WHEN
    val result = serviceMock.call("one")

    // THEN
    verify( serviceMock, times(1) ).
      call( eqTo("one") )

    assert(result == "123")
  }
```